# Wordpress files not update

Tags: php, wordpress

On wp-includes there are some files that responsible for some parts templates in the system, for example on "general-template.php" there is a function called "_wp_render_title_tag" which print the "title" tag.
When I'm trying to edit the code - nothing happen in my website.

Same in comment-template / category-template / etc.

What can be the problem of that? seems like the files do whatever they wants...

ps. when I'm delete the whole file - I get error.
but when editing only part or chaning something - nothing happen...

Comment: Do you using any caching plugin? Did you try in diff. browser/machine?

Comment: No plugins at all...